# Rails 5 missing template that was added to lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, model-view-controller

I have added into `application.rb` string

`config.paths['app/views'] << 'app/views/cabinet'`

and created a view 'app/views/cabinet/index.html.slim'.

But when I go to route `localhost:3000/manager/pages` (It uses layout `manager` if it make sence), Rails gives the error

`Manager::PagesController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do by overriding the mapping for the location of app/views but it doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Without knowing more about your code I would suggest you remove that config line from application.rb and simply use:

```
render 'cabinet/index'
```

from `PagesController#index` action.